# My assembly procedure doesn't seem to return

Tags: assembly, x86, stack, interrupt, real-mode

I'm trying to write a code to be ran as a bootloader. It should print `'Enter your name'`, then read user's name, then proceed to do other things, but I'm stuck at printing `'Enter your name!'`.

When I run this code, it does print `'Enter your name!'`, but no matter what I put as the next instruction under `say_hello` label, doesn't seem to work. In this case - I tried printing `'Test message'` next, but only `'Enter your name!'` gets printed on boot.

I checked that `print` procedure doesn't fall into infinite loop. I tried printing a single character from `ret_p` label before `ret` instruction and it worked. So my guess would be that I have something on the stack that I'm not aware of? But I have no idea where that could come from.

```
org 0x7c00


jmp 0:start ;zero the cs register

start:
  mov ax, cs
  mov ds, ax
  mov es, ax
  mov ss, ax
  mov sp, 0x8000 ;initialize stack

jmp 0:say_hello

; in register al procedure expects argument - character to print
print_char:
  mov ah, 0xe
  int 0x10
  hlt
  ret

; in register ax procedure expects argument - buffer text to print
print:
  mov bx, ax
  mov al, [bx]
  cmp al, 0x0
  je ret_p
  call 0:print_char
  inc bx
  mov ax, bx
  jmp 0:print
ret_p:
  ret

say_hello:
  mov ax, WELCOME_MSG
  call 0:print
  mov ax, TEST_MSG
  call 0:print

section .data

WELCOME_MSG: db 'Enter your name!', 0xd, 0xa, 0x0
TEST_MSG: db 'Test message', 0x0;, 0xd, 0xa, 0x0
BUFFER: times 64 db 0x0
```

P.S. I run the code on qemu with minix3

P.S.2 Don't worry about my bootloader lacking partition table and `0xaa55` ending, I write compiled code to first 446 bytes of disk.